# Querying Business Central/NAV Item Availability by Location through OData or the API

Tags: odata, dynamics-business-central

I'm struggling to find a quick method of querying currently 'available items' through the Business Central API or ODataV4 built-in queries and pages which can be set up as web services. The company has multiple locations holding stock. I'm looking to get a list by SKU of how many items are 'in stock' and 'not already committed to orders'.

I've been trying the following ODataV4 endpoints, set up by default in v18 using the Web Services screen. I'm using the URL composition:
`https://api.businesscentral.com/v2.0/tenant/environment/ODataV4/company/endpoint`

- `/ItemQuantities` - (Object Type: Query, Object ID: 2552) - Great, but shows summed data across all locations.
- `/ItemsByLocation` - (Object Type: Page, Object IDs: 491) - I am not finding documentation that tells me how to filter this by a specific location or use the matrixForm data.

Is anyone able to offer some pointers for me? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: Which version of Business Central are you working with? Is it cloud or on premise?

Comment: @kaspermoerch It is the cloud version 18.0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the endpoints you mention. Could you add a little more description of the URL composition?

Comment: Thanks @kaspermoerch. Original post updated.

Comment: Did you solve this Simon?